# trying to connect to eclipse marketplace gives InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

When I click on "Help / Eclipse Marketplace", I get a popup progress box that says "Retrieving data from http://marketplace.eclipse.org", waits long enough to be a network timeout, then displays the Eclipse Marketplace dialog with a popup that says java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.  The "details" button doesn't give anything further, and the "error log" gives a lot of data but does not give me any further information (someone else would know what it means, I guess).

I am on Windows 7 64-bit, running eclipse Indigo 3.7; as part of working on this problem, I did a "help / check for updates" and let it loose.  I ran it again and it said no updates were found.

I have looked at internet settings in IE (which I never use) and in Chrome (my default browser); both of them are set to auto-detect network connection settings.  The machine is in my home, using a wireless router to a cable ISP, so I don't think any proxy should be necessary.  However, I'm a programmer, not a network person, would be happy to learn about something else there that should be checked.

I enabled telnet on the windows machine and executed "telnet marketplace.eclipse.org 80"; it cleared the command screen and appeared to be waiting for input.  I entered the telnet control character and it popped back to the dos prompt.  There seems to be no connection issue to that domain on port 80.

My runtime environment is java 1.6.0_24; jre6 is the only installed execution environment that shows up in eclipse ("Windows / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs").

I found one post that claimed that turning ON Windows firewall fixed his issue; I looked and was displeased to find that Windows firewall was already turned on for my machine; I turned it off, but it did not change the error.  (I have a hardware firewall, don't know why I would need Microsoft's or BitDefender's.)

There are several SO posts on the subject, but none of them seem to fit me closely enough; some of the things I have tried above came from those posts.

There are one or two reported bugs on the issue in eclipse, but they seem to be at least a year old and are reportedly fixed.

Can someone please tell me how to solve this, or at least where to look?

Comment: They are comment the progress on twitter https://twitter.com/EclipseFdn
For now http://marketplace.eclipse.com embeds this thread from twitter

Comment: It's .org, actually, but thanks.  I never figured out how to look at the feed on the second link, but the first one told me that marketplace was up and running 5 hours ago, and now I can connect to it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://h-online.com/-1797226

Read the article above.  They were moving their servers and they hope to finish Sunday afternoon.

Comment: Thanks, I had not heard that.  How do I tell if they're done?  Does the telnet return not tell us that it's back up?

Answer (score 0):

i did all the work around.. finally installing JRE 6 worked like a magic ...  Try this!

Answer (score 0):

try this -vmargs -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true